# Swapping anchor pane inside an anchor pane with another anchor pane in JavaFX/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scene

I'm using Scene Builder 2.0 to create 2 of my fxml files (1 of it contain 2 anchor panes (seperated by SplitPane) and 1 button, and the other fxml contain 1 anchor pane). I wanted to swap the anchor pane in 1 of the fxml files to change after the button press.
So I define a method in my controller class :

```
@sfxml  //I'm using Scala
class UserEvent(private var secondanchorpane : AnchorPane,
private var thirdanchorpane : AnchorPane) {
def afterPress(e : ActionEvent){
Main.fooroot.getChildren.clear()  //fooroot is the root of the FXML files containing 2 original anchor pane and Main is a Scala object that stores the reference to fooroot
Main.fooroot.getChildren.add(thirdanchorpane)
 }
}
```

In the code above, only the scene is cleared but third anchor element is not shown on the scene. 
I assume that "Main.fooroot.getChildren.add(thirdanchorpane)" is not the correct code to swap the anchorpane, so is there any other alternative solution OTHER than creating additional anchor pane to the other fxml files and swapping the whole scene?